# Get the read or write path of an application

Tags: read-write

Is there a way where i can find the path an application is writing/reading a file from?

I used the resouce monitor(available in task manager) and to test it out, I opened notepad and saved it. it never accessed the path that I saved it in..But the file was saved.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this is a programming question? If not, you might be better off asking on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: opps..sorry for that..posted it in superuser..thank you Gareth